# Instalar Theme Primefaces Avalon - Netbeans

Tags: primefaces, netbeans

Comprei um tema do primeFaces (Avalon).
Mas não tenho ideia de como implementar ele no Netbeans.

Veio o arquivo.jar (avalon-theme-1.0.5.jar)
e páginas de testes, WEB-INF, resources (css,fonts,images,js) e sass.

Implantei a biblioteca no netbeans já, mas não sei como aplicar o tema? 
Alguém tem um manual que possa me passar? Estive procurando na net e estou bem confuso.

- A pasta 'resources' eu devo colocar onde?
- O arquivo avalon-theme-1.0.5.jar basta apenas importar na biblioteca do netbeans?
- No web.xml, deixei o seguinte param.

  primefaces.THEME

  primefaces-avalon-blue

Alguém pode me orientar?

Comment: Quando você baixa o zip do tema existe um arquivo .war dentro dele, você pode abri-lo e ver a estrutura de um projeto com o tema.

Answer (score 0):

Marcos,

- Coloque o arquivo .jar do tema na pasta webapp/WEB-INF/lib

No seu `web.xml` coloque assim:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>avalon-blue</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apenas colocando a Lib no projeto eu não consegui.
Para os que passaram pelo menos problema, segue solução:

Solicitei o arquivo 'avalon.war' que não veio na compra.

Feito isso, eu importei o arquivo para um  projeto novo e veio tudo pronto. Tinha muitas coisas pra se configurar.

Eclipse > File > Import > Web > WAR file.

;)